# Forzar la apertura de un link en el navegador y no en la app

Tags: javascript, html, css, mercadopago

Estoy teniendo un problema con unos links de MERCADO PAGO.

Estoy haciendo un sistema de ventas de clases online en HTML, CSS y JS plano.

Al final del proceso, tengo un link que me redirige a la venta mediante mercado pago.
Hasta ahí todo funciona correctamente.

Lo que me sucede es que al querer acceder al pago mediante el link, este abre la app, pero al abrir la app, pide ingresar con la contraseña de la cuenta y luego de eso manda a la página principal y el link de pago se pierde.

No puedo abrir el link.

Solo lo pude hacer si desinstalo la aplicación de Mercado Pago para que abra el link directamente en el navegador.

Pero teniendo la app, sucede eso.

He buscado en la documentación de MP pero todo indica que genere el link de pago de la única manera que existe, sin poder acceder al link mediante la app.

Hay alguna manera de forzar, desde el código de la página, de abrir el link en el navegador?

```
<div class="row d-flex my-5 justify-content-center">
    <a href="LINK DE MERCADO PAGO" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg text-dark disabled" id="button" name="button[]" target="_blank" onclick="open()">PAGÁ TUS CLASES</a>
</div>
```

(No sabría qué codigo mostrar, ya que es un  simple con el link en el)

He intentado con los tarhet _blank y _self pero no logro dar con la solución.

Muchas gracias.

EDIT: Todo el problema sucede cuando se accede desde dispositivos móviles.

Comment: app?? esto es android?

Comment: @Excorpion por lo que le entendi al usuario se refiere a que su sitio esta siendo visitado en un movil, y el mediante un link al clickearlo se le abre la app de `mercadopago`, el lo que quiere es que no le abra la app de `mercadopago` si no que se le abra la pagina web de mercado pago ahi mismo en el navegador.

Comment: Así es, lo aclaro con un edit en la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: El problema creo es por que la aplicación de mercado pago tiene linkeado el dominio para que se abra la aplicación, y entonces mas bien esa solución no te funcionara, por que hará lo mismo, si revisas la documentación creo que mas bien te funcionara integrar el [checkout Pro](https://www.mercadopago.com.mx/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-pro/introduction), que es solo el complemento y no toda la liga

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea eso mismo pensaba decir, enrealidad cualquier usuario que tenga la app instalada le va a ocurrir eso.

Comment: La URL es fija o se genera dependiendo de algun producto? En dichos casos puedes usar una redireccion mediante un sitio intermedio  que te lleve a la pagina, o un acortador de links, etc.

Comment: La url es fija, si... la creo desde la aplicación y la pego así como está en el código

Answer (score 0):

Cuando la App de MP te hace el callback luego de confirmar Pago viene el parametro merchant_account_id sin valor y te rompe la URL.
Te llega algo similar a esto merchant_account_id&status=approved y, evidentemente si parseas o usas status para algo no lo vas a poder obtener ya que te va a quedar una variable como merchant_account_id&status y no solo status.
Si el callback viene desde el browser, esto no sucede.